# Not able to import table to hive in different files (for e.g part-0000, part-00001, part-00002) using sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

***problem statement:* Ensure each tables file is partitioned in 3 files e.g. part-00000, part-00002, part-00003**

```
sqoop import-all-tables -m 3 --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username retail_dba --hive-import --hive-overwrite --create-hive-table --compress --compression-codec snappy --outdir java_output

/08/29 02:42:57 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop- training/compile/9cf789b552995b98bd700d07f4cb3de2/categories.jar
16/08/29 02:42:57 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
16/08/29 02:42:57 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
16/08/29 02:42:57 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
16/08/29 02:42:57 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
16/08/29 02:42:57 ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Error during import: No primary key could be found for table categories. Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_2),

> For the import-all-tables tool to be useful, the following conditions must be met:
>
> - Each table must have a single-column primary key or `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` option must be used.

Now as per your logs, `categories` table has no primary key.

So you need to add `--autoreset-to-one-mapper` in your sqoop command so that for the table with no primary key it uses 1 mapper.